# Renaming Node.js folder name

Tags: node.js, web, heroku, npm, node-modules

So actually I just started to learn web programming with node and express. I created a folder named "Node Web" inside my programming folder and do npm init in it. Right now, the web is already deployed in heroku. The question is I want to rename "Node Web" folder with a new name. So I tried renamed it from vscode explorer but I got this error

```
Error: Unable to move 'Node Web' into 'Programming'(Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'd:\Programming\Node Web'->'d:\Programming\New Name')
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, please quit all processes that access to this folder: heroku cli, explorer, node process, terminal ...

Comment: Bruh-_- thanks bro, you saved me or else maybe I'll spend hours on google try to fix this

Comment: Sometimes there are so many processes running. And things are mystic. All what helps will be to reboot your computer.